# WinServer 2019 Standard Https Issue

Tags: windows, google-chrome, https, windows-server-2019, hsts

Recently installed Windows Server 2019 Standard (legit and activated) and migrated my mail server over to this server. I noticed after I was done that I cannot browse the web if the website uses https. Below I attached pictures and I have tried to research and really haven't found much. Google Chrome will not let me even try to visit any https websites. While at the same time IE will let me continue on but websites do not load properly. Windows update is 100% up to date.

Google Chrome:

> [image]

Internet Explore:

> [image]

Comment: @wasif hasan if you are going to edit a question (in this case just to add a tag), please can you fix all of the issues (in this case inline the images)?

Comment: I didn't edit it I don't think. I see the images pop up. Sorry, this is my first time posting here.

Comment: My comment was addressed to the person who edited the question, not you. You have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @DavidPostill I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Comment: This sucks if no one has any ideas.